# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::put() in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, validation, debugging

When I'm trying to return errors via validation like below:

`return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();`

It gives me this error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::put()`

which is in: 
`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse.php line 133`

The code is:

```
/**
 * Flash a container of errors to the session.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\MessageProvider|array|string  $provider
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return $this
 */
public function withErrors($provider, $key = 'default')
{
    $value = $this->parseErrors($provider);

    $this->session->flash(
        'errors', $this->session->get('errors', new ViewErrorBag)->put($key, $value)
    );

    return $this;
}
```

**As you see it should use put method from ViewErrorBag not MessageBag!**

*Any help would be appreciated...*

Answer (score 2):

`get('errors', new ViewErrorBag)` will return a `ViewErrorBag` when the `errors` key doesn't exist in the session. In this case, `errors` does exist in the session, and it appears to be an instance of `MessageBag`. So, `get('errors', new ViewErrorBag)` returns the `MessageBag`, and then attempts to call `put()` on it, which gives you your error.

You need to find in your code where you're storing a `MessageBag` in the session `errors` key, and change that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should update your code like:

```
 return redirect()->back()
           ->withInput()
           ->withErrors($validator);
```

OR
 You need to update your composer :

```
composer dumpauto
```